# Inject HTML to be displayed on top of page at runtime

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript

I am looking for a way to inject HTML into an already loaded page in response to a user clicking the page.

Precisely, what I need to do is:

1. Capture a click
2. Generate a HTML string to be displayed
3. Inject that HTML string into the page, to be displayed **on top** of the current markup.

Of these, 1 is done and 2 is partially complete, so now I need to display the HTML string on top of the current markup (like a pop-up box). The injected markup should disappear when the markup behind it is clicked. How can I do this?

This is being developed as a feature of an Angular2 web app, so I'd like to achieve this using only typescript, HTML and CSS for styling, rather than use an existing library.

A few pointers to make things a little clearer:

- Generated HTML will be interactive, so it may be clicked on, not just a simple popup or alert.
- Generated HTML should be removed from the DOM when an area outside of that HTML is clicked.

Comment: Like a [Bootstrap Alert](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#alerts)?

Comment: Are you wanting the generated html to completely disappear from the DOM?

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek More like a bootstrap modal - the generated HTML will contain interactive objects such as buttons.

Comment: @Matthew, Yes. generated HTML should be removed from the DOM when an area outside of that HTML is clicked.

Comment: Well, I am not experienced in typescript but with JavaScript you could have the html in a separate file then call the `.load('page.html')` function. Then when the user clicks outside the container you could use the `.remove('#parent_div_of_inserted_html')` to remove it from the page. Not sure how to translate it into Typescript though.

Comment: This is a good suggestion but wouldn't work in my case. The base HTML of the page should not change (accept adding and removing the generated HTML), and the generated HTML will be created as a string variable.

Comment: not sure if I am understanding your need completely. My only other contribution I could try to make is create your string variable `var string: "<div class="content"></div>"` print that then you might be able to have a second variable that trims the first and last character, in this case the quotations, by using something like `var string_insert: string.substring(1, string.length-1);` then insert it into the html?

Comment: @Matthew that's exactly what I need to do, the question I'm asking is *how* can I insert that string into HTML.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133768/discussion-between-matthew-and-pythonnewb).

Comment: i believe what you are looking for is called the lightbox effect. i don't see why you wouldn't want to use an existing template since many of them exist and they are a pain to recreate. but if you are willing to recreate one using only css and html it is almost impossible i would use jQuery at least